# next-buffer: Browse through all open buffers using arrow keys but using C-x just one time

Tags: buffers

Via <kbd>C-x</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> (`next-buffer`) I can go to the next buffer. For every next buffer I have to do <kbd>C-x</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> again and again.

But I would like to do something like <kbd>C-x</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>...

Is it possible?

Of course I also knew `counsel-switch-buffer`. Where I can browse the buffers in the minibuffers list. But I would like to do it without the minibuffer list just with the arrow keys.

Comment: I would look into setting up a [hydra](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra).

Comment: Emacs 28 will ship a new `repeat-mode` that seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I bound `previous-buffer` and `next-buffer` to `[M-up]` and `[M-down]` respectively, works very well for navigating between buffers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until you can use `repeat-mode` in Emacs 28, the same could be achieved by a few lines of code:

```el
(defvar next-buffer-keymap
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [left]    'previous-buffer)
    (define-key map [C-left]  'previous-buffer)
    (define-key map [right]   'next-buffer)
    (define-key map [C-right] 'next-buffer)
    map)
  "Keymap for `next-buffer' commands.")

(advice-add 'previous-buffer
            :after (lambda (&rest _args)
                     (set-transient-map next-buffer-keymap)))
(advice-add 'next-buffer
            :after (lambda (&rest _args)
                     (set-transient-map next-buffer-keymap)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `repeat` command (<kbd>C-x</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, thereafter <kbd>z</kbd> as many times as you want):

<kbd>C-x</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>
<kbd>C-x</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>
<kbd>z</kbd>
<kbd>z</kbd>
<kbd>z</kbd>
...